# Using Apple Business Manager (VPP) can I distribute my APP to clients in various countries?

Tags: ios

Using Apple Business Manager (VPP), Can I distribute my app to clients in various countries using redemption codes created in one country or do I need to set up multiple Apple Business Manager Accounts?